# Vue.js - Vuexx : state value undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex

After user login authentication  ( LoginPage component ) the currentUserId is set in the store, but trying to get it later in another component ( ShoppingLists ) gives an undefined value ... what's wrong with my flow ?

here is my store.js

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    import getters from '@/vuex/getters'
    import actions from '@/vuex/actions'
    import mutations from '@/vuex/mutations'

    import vueAuthInstance from '../services/auth.js'

    Vue.use(Vuex)

    const state = {
      shoppinglists: [],
      isAuthenticated: vueAuthInstance.isAuthenticated(),
      currentUserId: ''
    }

    export default new Vuex.Store({
      state,
      mutations,
      getters,
      actions
    })
```

Here are the console.log output with related pieces of code

// LoginPage component submit button fires the login action

```
  methods: _.extend({}, mapActions(['login']), {
    clearErrorMessage () {
      this.hasError = false
    },
    submit () {
      return this.login({user: { email: this.email, password: this.password }})
      .then((logged) => {
        if (logged) {
          this.$router.push('shoppinglists')
        } else {
          this.hasError = true
        }
      })
    }
  }),
```

action.js

```
  login: ({ commit }, payload) => {
    payload = payload || {}
    return vueAuthInstance.login(payload.user, payload.requestOptions)
    .then((response) => {
     // check response user or empty
      if (JSON.stringify(response.data) !== '{}') {
        commit(IS_AUTHENTICATED, { isAuthenticated: true })
        commit(CURRENT_USER_ID, { currentUserId: response.data.id })
        return true
      } else {
        commit(IS_AUTHENTICATED, { isAuthenticated: false })
        commit(CURRENT_USER_ID, { currentUserId: '' })
        return false
      }
    })
  },
```

console.log
        mutations.js?d9b0:23
            state isAuthenticated:  true
        mutations.js?d9b0:27 
            committed state currentUserId:  1

At this point the store should be updated ....

// then the LoginPage component push the ShoppingListsPage 
when mounted it shoudl populates the shoppinglists

```
methods: _.extend({}, mapActions(['populateShoppingLists', 'createShoppingList']), {
  addShoppingList () {
    let list = { title: 'New Shopping List', items: [] }
    this.createShoppingList(list)
  }
}),
store,
mounted: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    console.log('GOING TO POPULATE STORE SHOPPINGLISTS FOR CURRENT USER')
    this.populateShoppingLists()
  })
}
```

console.log
        ShoppingListsPage.vue?88a1:52 
            GOING TO POPULATE STORE SHOPPINGLISTS FOR CURRENT USER

```
    actions.js?a7ea:9 
        TRYING TO GET currentUserId with GETTERS

        populateShoppingLists: ({ commit }) => {
          console.log('TRYING TO GET currentUserId with GETTERS')
          const currentUserId = getters.getCurrentUserId({ commit })
          console.log('ACTIONS: populateShoppingLists for user: ', currentUserId)
          return api.fetchShoppingLists(currentUserId)
          .then(response => {
            commit(POPULATE_SHOPPING_LISTS, response.data)
            return response
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            throw error
          })
        },
```

console.log

```
    getters.js?d717:9 
        GETTERS: currentUserId:  undefined
```

Getters returning an undefined value from the store

```
      getCurrentUserId: (state) => {
        console.log('GETTERS: currentUserId: ', state.currentUserId)
        return state.currentUserId
      },
```

**UPDATE**

**mutations.js**

```
    import * as types from './mutation_types'
    import getters from './getters'
    import _ from 'underscore'

    export default {
      [types.POPULATE_SHOPPING_LISTS] (state, lists) {
        state.shoppinglists = lists
      },
      [types.IS_AUTHENTICATED]  (state, payload) {
        console.log('committed state isAuthenticated: ', payload.isAuthenticated)
        state.isAuthenticated = payload.isAuthenticated
      },
      [types.CURRENT_USER_ID]  (state, payload) {
        console.log('committed state currentUserId: ', payload.currentUserId)
        state.currentUserId = payload.currentUserId
      }
    }
```

**mutation_types**

```
    export const POPULATE_SHOPPING_LISTS = 'POPULATE_SHOPPING_LISTS'
    export const IS_AUTHENTICATED = 'IS_AUTHENTICATED'
    export const CURRENT_USER_ID = 'CURRENT_USER_ID'
```

Comment: What do your mutations look like? My current hunch is a mutation occurring after login has overwritten the entire state.

Comment: thanks @wing for your feedback... I guess so ( looking in the Vue Tools, I see the currentId being set back to undefined... but why ??

Comment: Vue devtools should show you what is happening with each mutation. Inspect each one and you'll be able to identify which mutation is causing `state.currentUserId` to become `undefined`. If you're unable to progress from there, I recommend updating your question to include the output of each state change (you can do this by posting a screenshot of the devtools showing the mutation in question).

Comment: thanks @wing for your feedback , I solced it .. see my own answer. btw I need to get more doc on { commit, state } as parameters ...  if you know a good URL link , you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue , modifying the action populateShoppingLists
Need to pass the state as a parameter with the commit , so I can use the getters inside my action

```
populateShoppingLists: ({ commit, state }) => {
    let currentUserId = getters.currentUserId(state)
    console.log('currentUserId: ', currentUserId). // => userId: 1 Ok
    return api.fetchShoppingLists(currentUserId)
```